# How does maven replace text @env@ in application.yml?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

There is some profiles defined in pom.xml.

```
<profile>
  <id>test</id>
  <properties>
    <env>test</env>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

`spring.profiles.active: @env@` defined in application.yml and bootstrap.yml.
When I run `mvn install -P test`, text `@env@` in application.yml would be replaced by `test`.

**How does it work?**

**Why it does't work for bootstrap.xml?**

Comment: My assumption is that you should not use profiles where you can use Spring Boot profiles which are better in relationship with Spring boot....

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. But I must set value of `spring.profiles.active` when packaging like `mvn package -P test`.

Comment: You should give the profile during runtime via command line...read docs about that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for `application.yml` because you are obviously using the Spring Boot Starter Parent. See the POM here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml

The magic part is the `<resources>` configuration within that parent POM. You see that the application config files are explicitly copied with filtering. That is why the `maven-resources-plugin` resolves placeholders in these files.

If you want to add more files to be handled like this you can add your own `<resources>` section to your POM and extend it by more file patterns.